# Correlation via FFT for different image sizes

Tags: correlation, image-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Right now I am trying to match a small template image to a bigger one to see where the correlation is the highest.

I know that I can compute this by filtering the big image with a filter comprised by the image values of the small template.

However, this is really slow.

I also know that I can circumvent this filtering by transferring the images into the FFT domain, where the convolution becomes an easy pointwise multiplication.

But here I am stuck. Now the images are of different size in the FFT domain, how can I ever multiply them? Or do I need to do a FFT with regard to the same size? And if yes, which one is it?

Comment: Zero-pad the smaller image to match the larger one. Note that the location  of the top-left corner of the template image is where the cross-correlation will get a local maximum.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!